# R why wild card * does not work in combination with $?

Tags: r, wildcard

data$name*

I have a data file with many columns and i know how they begin and want to get them one by one just using the initial part of the name and using the wild card. but it doesn't seem to work with the $ sign. it expects something more

+

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: you can try `data[,grep("name",names(data))]`

Comment: this works, thanks
but can you help me understand also why
data$name*
does not work?

Comment: Why would you think that would work in `R` ?

Comment: I'm just ignorant, trying to understand if there are specific rules for when wildcard works and when it doesn't… I don't see the difference between having "name*" inside grep and having $name*...

Comment: i did find and read that post thread… but could not see an answer to my $ question… thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the example below:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c(1, 2, 3), name1 = c(1, 1, 2), colname = c(1, 1, 1)) 
col_sel <- grep("^name", colnames(df), value = TRUE)
df[col_sel]
```

`^` ensures that the name of the column begins with 'name'.